# How much data can I store in a LastPass secure note?

Tags: security, encryption

Does anyone know if there are limits to the amount of data you can store in a LastPass secure note?  I don't want to abuse the service but I also don't want to store a large note and then lose some of the data later on if they shrink the limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read here that it's 50k.  Someone questions if that's per note, but no one answered.  I believe it is, though.  My notes are well over 50k total.

http://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=43909